# .Net Core 2 Sql Server connection

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I wanted to try out .Net Core and created a new .Net Core 2 Webb application. I then added another .Net Core class library in order to use that as my Data Access layer. I thought I could use EF 6 and create a model based on my exsisting database. But I cannot select EF when using Add - New Item. How does Microsoft want us to connect to SQL Servers when using .Net Core?

Comment: Check the ASP.NET Core tutorials, especially [Working with Data in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/). Database-first isn't supported in EF Core though and was already frowned upon in MVC, Web API. Even in ASP.NET MVC though, EF was an additional package. You had to install it first.

Comment: Also check Julie Lerman's [articles on EF Core](http://thedatafarm.com/tag/efcore/) and Erik Jensen's [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) which add back some of the missing functionality like reverse-engineering an existing database. Julie Lerman has a (very good) EF Core course on Pluralsight which you can access for free through the Visual Studio Dev Essentials prorgram

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) or [Dapper](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-dapper-orm-with-asp-net-core/).